# How to tell which version of a gem a rails app is using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm investigating a rails app - the prod server has two version of a specific gem installed, how can I tell which version the prod app is using?

Comment: Are you asking which version of rails, or which version of some other gem?

Comment: Which version of a particular gem.

Comment: I have a gem frozen under vendors/gems, and then have a newer version of the gem installed in the default gems location.  I'm looking from something from rails that says "I loaded this gem from this location".

Answer (score 192, accepted):

In Rails 3 and Rails 4, use `bundle show`

In Rails 2, `rake gems` will print out what gems, dependencies, and versions are installed, frozen, etc.

Comment: This will only work if the gem as been specified in the environment.rb file.  If the developer just required it somewhere, rake gems won't work.

Comment: (Or in one of the config/environments/* files, depending on your RAILS_ENV.)

Comment: If you want to filter the list do `bundle show | grep gem_name`, example for compass: `bundle show | grep compass`

Comment: So what does it mean when you type bundle show and you get a bunch of Gems with versions including "rails 2.3.17) and you type rake gems and you get what looks like a legend (I=Installed, etc) but no gems/versions?  Do I have rails version 2 or not?  Maybe I have rails version 2 and a more advanced bundler?  Is this good/bad?  (Yes, I know it's bad to have such an old version of rails, I want to know if it's catastrophic to have such a mismatched (if it is) rails and bundler).

Answer (score 49):

If you use bundler, then you can get the version from

```
bundle show [gemname]
```

Comment: I came to this question because I am trying to move _to_ bundler (probably many people also, because Heroku now requires this)

Comment: This is deprecated. Use `bundle info [gemname]` instead.

Answer (score 39):

It took me longer than expected to find and sort through this information so I wanted to post it here in one place for others to view.  I also wanted to clarify this a bit for Rails 3:

- script/about has been replaced with `rake about`  The details are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#about).  If you are interested a list of all the command line changes for Rails 3 they can be found [here](http://pragprog.com/wikis/wiki/ChangesInRails30/version/40).
- `rake gems` does not work in Rails 3.  Instead you should use `bundle show`

As an example, you can save all versions of your gems to a file for viewing with:

`gem list > all_gems.txt`

and you can see what versions your Rails app is using with:

`bundle show > project_gems.txt`

Using an editor like Vim you can easily use vimdiff to see the changes

Answer (score 8):

In the terminal

```
  bundle show <gem-name>
  bundle show | grep <gem-name>
```

or

```
  gem list | grep <gem-name>
```

For example:

```
  bundle show rails
  bundle show | grep rails

  gem list | grep rails
```

Answer (score 6):

There probably is a more direct way to find this out, but if you load up a console and require a specific version like so:

```
gem 'RedCloth', '3.0.4'
```

It will tell you what version is already activated:

```
=> Gem::LoadError: can't activate RedCloth (= 3.0.4, runtime) for [], already activated RedCloth-4.2.2
```

Answer (score 5):

There's also a list in `Gemfile.lock`, located in the root directory of your app.

For this reason I leave `Gemfile.lock` out of my `.gitignore`.  This has saved me more than once when I forgot to specify the gem version in `GemFile`, and a gem got updated with breaking changes.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `script/about`. Your `config/environment.rb` also has information about it.

In your `config/environment.rb` you can specify which version of a particular `gem` the application should use. However if you have multiple versions of a `gem` installed on your machine and you do not specify the version, the latest version of that gem will be used by the application.

Answer (score 4):

```
gem list <gemname>
```

It will show all the matching gems e.g if some one do

```
gem list rack
```

Then th output will be as following

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rack (1.6.4)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2, 0.5.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

`script/about` will tell you what versions of the core Rails and Rack gems you're using, but not anything else.  Ideally, if you look in `config/environment.rb`, there should be a section that looks like this:

```
# Specify gems that this application depends on and have them installed with rake gems:install
# config.gem "bj"
# config.gem "hpricot", :version => '0.6', :source => "http://code.whytheluckystiff.net"
# config.gem "sqlite3-ruby", :lib => "sqlite3"
# config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"
```

With any luck, the author of the app will have included any required gems and versions there.  However, the versions are optional in this file, and ultimately nothing stops an inexperienced developer from just slapping a `require 'rubygems'; require 'some_random_thing'` at the top of any given file.

If you see that a gem is being required, but no version is specified, you can type `gem list` to see all the versions of all the gems on the system.  By default, it will be using the latest one available.

Comment: Does your script/about tell you about gems? Mine just tells me what version of ruby, rails and environment I'm using.

Comment: Right, Rails (and Rack) are both gems, and script/about will tell you what versions of them are running, along with the core Rails stuff (ActiveSupport, etc) but it won't tell you about any other gems.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle exec gem which gem_name
```

Is probably what you can use:

```
$› bundle exec gem which rails
/Users/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@gemset/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails.rb
```

Comment: I was looking for information about which version of a globally-installed gem was being executed in an arbitrary folder and this led me to what I believe is the correct solution - `gem which gem_name`

Answer (score 2):

If you use bundler, then you can get the version using:

```
bundle info [gemname]
```

Answer (score 1):

bundle show gemname
I.e for devise you have to write like

```
bundle show devise
```

and it will printout the current gem version.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version, used `bundle show gem_name`

```
[DEPRECATED] use `bundle info gem_name` instead of `bundle show gem_name`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one for local gem :

```
gem list gemname | grep -P '(^|\s)\Kgemname(?=\s|$)'
```

If you use bundle:

```
bundle exec gem list gemname | grep -P '(^|\s)\Kgemname(?=\s|$)'
```

Answer (score -8):

In Gemfile , there should be the answer:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
```

Comment: `Gemfile` won't always explicitly declare a version number.