# How to check if a gem is installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed data_mapper for a Sinatra project. Curious, why is it when I do `gem install brew`, I can `$ which brew` and get the path of its location and can't for data_mapper? This works for some gems and doesn't for others.

How do I verify a gem is installed properly? Would checking the version assure the gem is downloaded correctly?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32986687/3728916

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### General solution

To get the full list of gems that are installed:

```
gem list
```

To test for a particular gem, you can use `-i` with a regex:

```
gem list -i "^gem_name$"
```

(Credit to Timo in the comments for this technique.)

---

##### Specific solution for OP

If you can't find data_mapper, it may be that the gem name is different from what you expect.

Also, if you're just doing `which brew` to find brew, you aren't finding the gem called brew, you're finding the location of the brew executable. Try `gem which brew` instead.

If you're looking for data_mapper by doing `which data_mapper`, you probably won't find it. `which` is a unix program for finding unix executables, and data_mapper probably doesn't have one.

Since your goal is to verify a gem is installed with the correct version, use `gem list`. You can limit to the specific gem by using `gem list data_mapper`.

To verify that it's installed *and working*, you'll have to try to `require` the gem and then use it in your code.

Comment: `gem list` showed I have data_mapper. Does `gem which brew` find the executable? It looks like a .rb file

Comment: `gem which somegemname` shows the path to (I think) the file that loads when you do `require 'somegemname'`. In general, gems don't have 'an executable' in the way that a program you'd discover via regular unix `which` do.

Answer (score 42):

In case you want to use the check in a script, this gives a better output (true or false) and appropriate exit code:

```
gem list -i <gem_name>
```

Alternatively add the version option:

```
gem list -i <gem_name> -v version
```

Comment: `gem list` takes as an argument a regexp to match against. So in case you would say something like `gem list -i zip` there's potentially very many different gems this might match (`gem list -r zip | wc -l` returns 197 as of this writing). However if you are particularly interested of the zip gem you should tell say so in the regexp zip, i.e. `gem list -i ^zip$`. Otherwise `gem install spain_zip_codes && gem list -i zip` => true, which is probably never what you want with this.

Comment: to test for the exact name use `-e` like `gem list -ie zip`

Comment: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
    Illformed requirement ["version"]`

said this for me. `gem which seira` works to tell the version tho

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `bundle` for your project then use below command to check for the exact match of your gem within the project.

`bundle info ^data_mapper$`

Answer (score 0):

For script usage, `gem query` probably is better:

```
gem query --silent --installed --exact rubygems --version 2.0.0
```