# How to access the version of a gem from within Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the version of a gem using just Ruby? I'd rather not use a system call and grep it the shells output like:

```
`gem search passenger`.scan(/(?:\(|, *)([^,)]*)/).flatten.first
=> "2.2.9"
```

Can't I just get it somehow with:

```
Gem::Version
```

I just don't know how to specify the gem I want, like in this case I want to get the Passenger gem's newest version.

Comment: Closely related, older, but less clear if from CLI or from within Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112754/determining-which-rubygem-youre-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you on your way.  This searches the **remote index** for the latest version of a specific gem.

```
$ irb
>> require "rubygems"
>> dep = Gem::Dependency.new "passenger", Gem::Requirement.default
>> Gem::SpecFetcher.fetcher.find_matching dep
=> [[["passenger", #<Gem::Version "2.2.9">, "ruby"], "http://gems.rubyforge.org"]]
```

Answer (score 10):

The [rubygems' API](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rdoc/) is well documented.

The example you've been looking for:

```
>>> require 'rubygems'
>>> si = Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems
>>> gems = si.find_name('rails')
>>> gems.each { |gem| puts gem.version.version }
2.3.5
```

Comment: As of Ruby 1.9.3, this method is now deprecated and will spit out a seemingly infinite ream of warnings.

Answer (score 3):

From "[Determining which rubygem you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112754/determining-which-rubygem-youre-using)":

```
Gemname::VERSION::STRING
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing that works is outlined in this answer to a duplicate question:
"[Get version of gem within Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046297/298664)".

```
Gem.loaded_specs[$NAME_OF_GEM].version
```

Know however that for this to work, you'll need to have at least one file in the `lib` directory.