# Get version of gem within ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to require a gem and then get the version number of that gem from within ruby?

Comment: This isn't a dupe of the linked question; this question is asking about the way to get the version of a loaded gem, while the linked question is asking how to query the version of a gem that is installed on the system.  They are very different things.

Comment: They are just giving out-of-code answers here, but both are asking for same thing, so I’d say this is a dupe, even if the answers are wrongly voted there.

Answer (score 15):

You could try

```
Gem.loaded_specs[$NAME_OF_GEM].version
```

Comment: In general: RubyGems is actually a Ruby library. The `gem` commandline program is actually just a very thin wrapper around that library. Everything you can do with the `gem` command (and more), you can also do with the RubyGems library. The only problem is documentation, although the code itself is well tested and largely well written and can thus sometimes serve as a substitue for documentation.

Comment: I found out that for this to work, you'll need to have at least one file in the `lib`directory.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from `Gem.loaded_specs`, there are also [`Gem.latest_spec_for`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Gem/latest_spec_for/class)

```
Gem.latest_spec_for('rails').version.to_s
# '3.2.8'
```